# How do we calculate the rate of interest in the total amount of compound interest formula

Tags: algorithm, math, finance

Referring the link
[Is there a Java API or built-in function for solving annuity problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143180/is-there-a-java-api-or-built-in-function-for-solving-annuity-problems/1143242#1143242)

Where the Sum of amount S,  with periodic investment R, for term n, and rate of interest as i, is given by formula:

```
S = R * [(1+i)^n - 1] / i
```

When I need to find the i, i.e, the rate of interest when other variable is given, then it looks like a complex equation of type:

```
A * i = (1+i)^n - 1
```

where A = S/R, a know constant and n is also known.

This becomes an equation which is not straight forward to solve for i. So how do we solve this kind of equation? Whether gradient descent approach to find the best fit solution of trail error is better for this?

Comment: *"Whether gradient descent approach to find the best fit solution of trail error is better for this?"*: what is "better"? This is going to be a matter of opinion, making this question off topic here. If however you have not managed to solve the problem, then please focus your question on your attempt (provide code) and what exactly goes wrong (input/output/error).

Comment: You have options. A fast but fairly complicated way would be to use Newton's Method on f(i) = (R * [(1+i)^n - 1] / i) - S. A simpler but slower method would be binary chop. Which is 'better' depends on your project's priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is a good candidate for finding the value of  so that  = ( + 1) − 1

#### Definitions and assumptions

- is the interest rate to be determined, like 0.015 (i.e. 1.5%), and will not be negative.
- is the given number of periods, i.e. the number of times at which a fixed payment  will be made. It is a positive integer.
- is /, i.e. the target amount divided by the amount of the recurring payment. All these variables are positive.
- ≥ :  represents the number of payments if the interest were 0. As the interest rate is not negative, this number of payments  should not be less than  − the idea of interest is that the sum of the individual payments will be less than the target amount.

Before applying Newton's method, let's first substitute with  =  + 1:

( − 1) =  − 1

which is equivalent with finding the roots of this function:

() =  −  + −1

To use Newton's method, we also need the derivative of :

'() = <sup>−1</sup> −

#### Choosing a good starting  for Newton's method

This derivative ' has one root that is a positive real number: <sub>0</sub> = (/)<sup>1/(−1)</sup>. As we assumed  ≥  (see above), we know <sub>0</sub> ≥ 1. This  represents a local minimum of  (the original function):  is decreasing in the interval [1, <sub>0</sub>), and increasing in the interval (<sub>0</sub>, +∞). The obvious root =1 will be in the first range, and so the one we want to find in the second. We should thus make sure to start Newton's method with  > <sub>0</sub>, and then it will work out fine.

Here is a graphical representation of () (with =70, =12):

[image]

In this concrete case, <sub>0</sub> is 1,17389377... the minimum in the above depicted curve. I would suggest  = 1 + 2(<sub>0</sub> − 1) as starting point for  Newton's method, so that it is in the section of the function that is ascending with a positive curve. This will ensure a very fast approach to the root we want to find.

Here is an implementation in a JavaScript snippet, where you can input the variables, and the interest rate is calculated with Newton's method.

```js
function calculate(S, R, n) {
    if (!(S > 0 && R > 0 && n > 0 && S / R > n)) return;
    const A = S/R;
    // Define the function and its derivative, in terms of x (i.e., interest + 1)
    const f = x => x ** n - A * x + A - 1;
    const df = x => n * x ** (n - 1) - A;
    
    const xLow = (A / n) ** (1 / (n - 1));
    // Newton's method
    let x = 2*xLow - 1; // Initial guess
    let y = f(x);
    let counter = 0;
    while (y > 1e-6) {
        x -= y / df(x);
        y = f(x);
        counter++;
    }
    return { // Return both the interest and the number of iterations
        interest: x - 1, // Convert coefficient to interest rate
        iterations: counter
    };
}


// I/O handling
const [inpTarget, inpPayment, inpPeriods, outInterest, outIterations] =
      document.querySelectorAll("input, span");
document.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    const target = +inpTarget.value;
    const payment = +inpPayment.value;
    const periods = +inpPeriods.value;
    const result = calculate(target, payment, periods);
    outInterest.textContent = result ? (result.interest * 100).toFixed(2) + "%" : "Invalid input";
    outIterations.textContent = result ? result.iterations : "";
}
refresh();
```

```html
Target amount: <input id="inpTarget" type="number" min="1" value="10000"><p>
Payment: <input id="inpPayment" type="number" min="1" value="300"><p>
Number of periods: <input id="inpPeriods" type="number" min="1" max="1000" value="24"><p>

Interest: <span></span><p>
Iterations: <span></span>
```

The maximum error margin is set to 0.000001, more than enough to get an accurate percentage.

As you can see from running the snippet, the number of iterations to get that percentage is small, like 3 or so.